# pandas fill created sheet row by row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following python code

```
sheet_a = pd.read_excel(open('c:\\upload\\' + f,'rb'), skiprows=1, sheetname='a')
sheet_b = pd.read_excel(open('c:\\upload\\' + f,'rb'), skiprows=1, sheetname='b')
```

Within these two sheets, I have two columns that I am creating from scratch, `Team` and `Full Name`.  The team name will be the same for all rows, so:

```
sheet_a['Team'] = "Team A"
sheet_b['Team'] = "Team B"
```

but I can't figure out how to create a value row by row.  In order to populate each user's `Full Name` column, I'm trying to join the `First Name` column with the `Last Name` column from that same row to create `Bob Smith` from `Bob` and `Smith`:

```
sheet_a['Full Name'] = row['First Name'] + ' ' + row['Last Name']
sheet_b['Full Name'] = row['First Name'] + ' ' + row['Last Name']
```

Then I finish things off with:

```
sheets = [ sheet_a, sheet_b ]   
all_sheets = pd.concat(sheets,ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
    all_sheets.to_csv('c:\\upload\\temp2.csv', columns=fields, index=False, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

The creation of the `Team` column/rows works fine, but I'm getting the following error for my attempt at creating a `Full Name` row by row:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 77, in <module>
    sheet_a['Full Name'] = row['First Name'] + ' ' + row['Last Name']
NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

Apart from this concatenation row by row thing, everything else in the script works flawlessly.

Comment: Could you please print the output of `sheet_a.columns` and `sheet_b.columns`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Harry', 'Hermione'], 'Last Name': ['P
   ...: otter', 'Granger']})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  First Name Last Name
0      Harry    Potter
1   Hermione   Granger

In [4]: df['Full Name'] = df['First Name'] + ' ' + df['Last Name']

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  First Name Last Name         Full Name
0      Harry    Potter      Harry Potter
1   Hermione   Granger  Hermione Granger
```

The trick here is that you refer to the entire column from your existing `DataFrame` using something like `sheet_a['First Name']` that gives you a column of first names. You can then concatenate the column of first names to a column of last names and get a column of full names.

Comment: You seem to be manually assigning the first/last name elements here - but I cannot do that as I'm importing something with 250,000 rows.  How do I do this if I cannot assign the values like you are here (`pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Harry', 'Hermione']`)

Comment: He's just creating a table like the one that you're working with there. The example provided is demonstrating that you can do the same string concatenation you did at a single row level across the entire dataset by using the entire columns (i.e., with `df['First Name']` rather than `row['First Name']`).

Comment: Oh... this makes sense now that I re-read it back over.  Sometimes it's hard to not think in Excel terms but in DataFrame terms.  This works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

@Oliver's answer is perfectly fine. But in bit similar cases it is useful to know about the `pandas.DataFrame.apply()` method. It would be used like this in this scenario:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"First Name":["Harry", "Hermione"], "Last Name":["Potter",
   ...:  "Granger"]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
  First Name Last Name
0      Harry    Potter
1   Hermione   Granger

In [4]: def concat_name(row):
   ...:     return row["First Name"] + " " + row["Last Name"]
   ...: 

In [5]: df["Full Name"] = df.apply(concat_name, axis=1)

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
  First Name Last Name         Full Name
0      Harry    Potter      Harry Potter
1   Hermione   Granger  Hermione Granger
```

Instead of writing your own function it is of course possible to introduce lambda's

```
In [7]: df["Full Name"] = df.apply(lambda row: " ".join(row[["First Name", "Last Name
   ...: "]]), axis=1)
```

Which is maybe even more readable. Just note `axis=1` in the `apply` method, to iterate over rows not columns, which is default I think. `apply` is useful because you can write quite complicated functions.

Comment: This is great - I always love to know multiple ways of doing things.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could spread the knowledge, use it well, young padawan!